Why is 1 ppm considered equal to 1 mg/dm3?
I usually work with percentages, so am not familiar with parts per million (ppm) fraction (ratio) method.
My teacher taught me that $1~\pu{ppm} = 1 ~\pu{mg/dm^3}$ without proof, so I looked in the internet for proof. It goes somewhat goes like this:
$1~\pu{ppm} = \frac{1 ~\pu{g}}{\pu{1E6g}} = \frac{\pu{1E-3g}}{\pu{1E3g}} = \frac{\pu{ 1 mg}}{\pu{1 kg}}$
density of water $=\pu{ 1000 kg m^-3} =\pu{1 kg dm^-3} $
$1~\pu{ppm} = \frac{\pu{ 1 mg}}{\pu{1 kg}} \times \pu{1 kg dm^-3} = \pu{1mg dm^-3}$
My confusion is, first I was taught that ppm is dimensionless since it is a ratio, but clearly "$\pu{mg/dm^3}$" is not dimensionless. Secondly, wouldn't this proof only be valid for aqueous solutions, since we multiply the density of water with the w/w ratio (ppm) (from my understanding, the w/w ratio (ppm) value here is the ratio between solute and solvent water, hence the above proof).
Please correct me if I am wrong and help me understand this concept.
P.S- Sorry for asking another question in the same post. This is a related question that arose while writing the post: for a solution (mixture) of A and B, does 1 ppm mean
(1) $\frac{m_A \times 10^6}{m_B}$
or
(2) $\frac{m_A \times 10^6}{m_A + m_B}$ ?

Consider how far off that would be using tungsten, 19 times denser than water. $1mg/dm^3$ would be 1/19 as strong. (Or mercury, 13 times as dense.)

@DrMoishePippik And here I wanted to criticize OP or poor formatting and you also write units wrong. With MathJax packet like \pu is needed, otherwise unit is slanted. Overuse of bold is arguably even worse.

@Mithoron I apologize. I used bold as a way of emphasizing on certain phrases. English is not my mother tongue so If I was unclear anywhere I can clarify and fix the error.

How to interpret parts-per notations? Is 1 ppb equal to 1 μg/kg?

The question should rather be  When is 1 ppm considered equal to 1 mg/dm3?

It surely isn't considered equal to 1mg/fl oz! ;-)

If you are familiar with $\pu{\%}$, but not with $\pu{ppm}$ and $\pu{ppb}$, then imagine that $\pu{\%}$ is nothing else but another syntax for $\pu{pph}$ (parts per hundred = per cent).
$\pu{1 ppm}$ is not considered automatically by default to be equal to $\pu{1 mg dm−3}$, similarly as $\pu{1 \%}$ is not considered automatically by default to be equal to $\pu{10 g dm−3}$.
$$\pu{1 ppm} = \frac{\pu{1 whatever} }{ \pu{E6 same whatever}}$$
$$\pu{1 \%} = \frac{\pu{1 whatever} }{ \pu{100 same whatever}}$$
$\pu{1 \%} = \pu{1 pph}$ may mean $\pu{10 mg/g}$, or $\pu{10 mmol/mol}$, or $\pu{10 L/m3}$, or $\pu{10 g/L}$ with assumption density is $\pu{1 kg/L}$. That is why is often explicitly said (and highly recommended to be used) mass percent, volume percent, mass/volume percent, molar percent, or using abbreviations % (w/w), ppm (v/v), ppm (w/v)}, ppt (n/n).
In context of air analysis, $\pu{\%}$, $\pu{ppm}$, $\pu{ppb}$, $\ce{ppt}$ are implicitly assumed being respective molar or volume fractions (assumed ideal gas behavior).
In context of sweet-water-like analysis with $\rho \approx \pu{1 g/mL}$ , $\pu{\%}$, $\pu{ppm}$, $\pu{ppb}$, $\ce{ppt}$ are implicitly assumed being respective mixed mass/volume fraction. $\pu{1 ppm} (\text{w/v}) = \pu{1 mg/L}$ therefore pretends it is $\pu{1 mg / kg}$, so it is unitless as all other homegeneous %(x/x) or pp(m/b/t)(x/x) combinations.
Note at high % values, it is often meant as mass/mass percent, not mass/volume percent. So the explicit forms are highly recommended.
In other scenarios, guessing the meaning of default % or ppx can be a tricky business with a risk of confusion and errors. As mentioned in the referred other post, it once caused emergency of an airliner due failure of its engines. Fortunately, all airliners are excellent gliders.
To prevent confusions:

IUPAC does not recommend using implicit ppx and % units at all.
If to be used, IUPAC recommends explicit verbose or (x/x) forms.
IUPAC recommends using explicit units like $\pu{mg/L}$.


Response to feedback:
% and ppm always relate to the all content. E.g. 20 % (w/w) solution of a salt A in water means $\pu{20 g}$ of A + $\pu{80 g}$ of water ( = about $\pu{80 mL}$).
Examples when $\pu{1 ppm} \ne \pu{1 mg/dm3}$ :
$\pu{1 ppm}$ of $\pu{CO}$ in air, or $\pu{1000 ppm}$ of sulfur in steel. The same for 1 % of $\ce{CO2}$ in air or 10 % of $\ce{Ni}$ in steel.
Your proof starts with assuming ppm = ppm (w/w), what is often right, but not always.
$\pu{1 mg/dm3}$ is tricky writing of $\pu{1 mg/kg}$, assuming density $\ce{1 kg/dm3}$, therefore dimensionless as well.

If you dissolved $\pu{90 g}$ of a salt $\ce{A}$ in $\ce{10 g}$ of water (there are such salts), would the solution have concentration 90 % (w/w), or 900 % (w/w) ? (the former)
Imagine %=pph as "how many of these 100 objects is this?" and ppm "how many of these 1000000 objects is this?"
A sample cannot contain more than 100 % of a substance nor more than 1000000 ppm of it, as it means pure substance.
So $\%\ \text{(w/w)} = \frac{m_1}{\sum{m}} \cdot 100$
$\text{ppm (w/w)} = \frac{m_1}{\sum{m}} \cdot \pu{e6}$.

this answer cleared most of my confusion about when we use w/v or w/w. only confusion I have now is, does 1 ppm mean
(1) $\frac{m_A \times 10^6}{m_B}$
or
(2) $\frac{m_A \times 10^6}{m_A + m_B}$ ? I have this confusion because we can't calculate the second ratio from the formula since they are weight and a volume.

Also, I would like to ask, is the proof I wrote correct? Do we really need to bring water in to this proof? or as you mentioned in your comment, "The question should rather be When is 1 ppm considered equal to 1 mg/dm3?", this only applies to special instances like aqueous solutions. Could you give me some examples when 1 ppm isn't considered equal to 1 mg/dm3?

Replying to your comment on this post- so do we use 1) formula or 2) formula to calculate ppm. another answer suggested, since practical use of ppm is to express the concentration of a smaller solute, 1) formula is used. I want to confirm if that formula is also correct theoretically, or if the 2) formula is the correct formula.

I have moved my comments to my answer.

The idea that 1 ppm is practically equivalent to 1 mg/L is true, approximately, but only when speaking about liquids, especially water.
Most commonly encountered liquids have densities that are close to water's.  For example, baby oil (i.e. mostly high-MW alkanes) has a density of 0.8 g/L.  So if you used the 1 ppm = mg/L approximation, you'd be off by less than 20%.
Your confusion as to whether ppm is a ratio (e.g. of the mass of solute to the mass of water) or a fraction (e.g. the mass of solute to the summed mass of solute plus water) is understandable.  I don't know how it is formally defined, but in practice, unless you are using ppm to express relatively high concentrations like 100,000 ppm, it won't matter much.  The mass of solute is negligible compared to the mass of solvent at say 100 ppm, and so the difference between the two is not significant for most practical work.  If you're trying to get an accuraccy to five decimal places or something, it might matter, but if two or three digits of accuracy is all you need, just assume ppm means whatever is more convenient to you at the time.

Is there a standard system of definitions (like for SI system) for these units, set by scientists. If there is I would greatly appreciate if you could provide me a link to it. Thank you

As you explain in the opening sentences, so much accuracy is lost by ignoring the density of the solution that the contribution of the solute is irrelevant.
